# Diffentiable function only at zero

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a case where $f$ is differentiable at $0$ but not any other point?

Comment: We might want to put stronger conditions on the function, like continuity. Then take any of the standard continuous nowhere differentiable functions $g(x)$, and let $f(x)=x^2g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. Consider the function $f= x^2$ when $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $-x^2$ otherwise.

This map is continuous only at 0, and in fact can be shown using a simple limit argument to also be differentiable there!

Answer (score 2):

Try $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Notationally succinct: $f(x)=x^2\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x)$